# Overcoming Auth error when interacting with SharePoint Online using REST API

Tags: python, azure, sharepoint

Now the error I get from the function below which is trying to list the files in a sharepoint folder, after updating to authenticate by cert, is:

```
An error occurred: AuthenticationContext.acquire_token_for_app() got an unexpected keyword argument 'client_credential'
```

When called as follows:

```
list_files_in_sharepoint_with_cert(
    '123456789',
    '987654321', 
    'c:\\users\\qqq\\xxx.pfx',
    'https://xxx.sharepoint.com',
    '/sites/yyy/Shared Documents/')
```

Code has been updated to use certificate, but I think there's something wrong in how I'm using the cert to authenticate.

Also corrected Azure app permissions as follows:
[image]

Here's the code for the function.

```
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.runtime.auth.client_credential import ClientCredential
from office365.runtime.auth.token_response import TokenResponse
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext


def list_files_in_sharepoint_with_cert(tenant_id, client_id, certificate_path, sharepoint_site_url, sharepoint_folder_url):
    """
    Lists files in a specified SharePoint folder or entire site using certificate-based authentication.

    :param tenant_id: Azure AD Tenant ID.
    :param client_id: The Azure AD application (client) ID.
    :param certificate_path: Path to the .pfx or .cer certificate file.
    :param sharepoint_site_url: The URL of the SharePoint site.
    :param sharepoint_folder_url: The optional URL of the SharePoint folder.
    """
    try:
        # Authenticate
        authority_url = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}'
        auth_ctx = AuthenticationContext(authority_url)
        client_credential = ClientCredential(client_id, certificate_path)
        
        breakpoint()
        auth_ctx.acquire_token_for_app(client_credential=client_credential)

        ctx = ClientContext(sharepoint_site_url, auth_ctx)

        # Rest of the function remains the same as before...

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Azure AD app permissions for SharePoint are now [supported only with certificate authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread). You have a mixture of "Delegated" and "Application":

Namely, you have the "Sites.FullControl.All" row in your application registration, and ask for "all scopes" (in fact, you do not specify any scope, this asks for all of them by default). And your code is using the "client secret" (this is weaker than a certificate).

You can (either should work):

- Remove the "Sites.FullControl.All" (application scope). To read/write files or folders, you don't need it anyway.
- Use a certificate as a "secret" instead of the keystroke (i.e. instead of the "client secret")
- Explicitly specify the scopes when making connection, and do not include the application-level scope.

Comment: Thanks! Updated to use cert and modified Azure as shown. Now getting an auth error??

Comment: The `acquire_token_for_app` does not seem to have the parameter `client_credentaial`. I am not sure about python library, you could try to follow the tutorial example: https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/ConnectionWithCert.md

Comment: would you please provide us with an update on the status of your issue?